# Prevent certain HTML tags from rendering with Python

Tags: python, html, filter, flask, xss

Say I have a string:

```
string = '<img src="image.png"><input type=text>'
```

I have a function which turns the string into HTML markup and removes all tags but `<img>` tags like so:

```
VALID_TAGS = ['img']

def sanitizeHTML(value):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(value)

    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        if tag.name not in VALID_TAGS:
            tag.hidden = True

    return Markup(soup.renderContents())
```

If I pass the string though the function, it would return `<img src="image.png">` as that is the only HTML tag valid.

As you can see, the `<input>` tag doesn't even appear in the string. How would I keep `'<input type=text>'` in the string but NOT render it so it will appear as text and not HTML.

How would I do this? Thanks.

Comment: You can just escape input tag, so it will be rendered as text in your browser. For example, <input type=text> will be &lt;input type=text&gt;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, I would use the `bleach` module - [documentation here](https://bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Bleach takes care of sanitizing your HTML tags and HTML-escaping the "unsafe" tags.

Here's a sample program illustrating how you might use bleach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bleach

def sanitizeHTML(value):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(bleach.clean(value,tags=VALID_TAGS,attributes=VALID_ATTRIBUTES),"html5lib")
    return soup.renderContents()

VALID_TAGS = ['img']
VALID_ATTRIBUTES = ['src']

string = '<img src="image.png"><input type=text>'
result = sanitizeHTML(string)

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

bleach [is deprecated](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach/issues/698), as I can see [nh3](https://nh3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a modern replacement. nh3.clean_text function is doing escaping, but for you case you may need to implement something on top as it's has not same behavior like bleach.